# Visit to Bangkok for Canadian expatriate

Tags: visas, canadian-citizens, bangkok

I am a Canadian citizen but living as an expatriate in Dubai, UAE. Is it true I can get a tourist visa to Bangkok on entry into the country? I am concerned because the local Thai consulate does not ease aquisition of a visa. It is not open on weekends and is only open for 3 hours 9-12 in the morning.

Comment: I commented out your second question about medication which should be asked separately.  Please feel free to post it as a new question if you wish.  You can see the old text by clicking the "edit" button.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as a Canadian citizen, you do not need a [visa to visit Thailand](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Thailand) as long as your visit is lesser than 30 days and is in the capacity of a tourist.